# c# Highlight Numbers smaller code snip

Tags: c#

I am creating a bingo machine, I have code so once pressed it will check what numbers have been called and highlight those numbers that have been called from the bingo machine.

I am wondering is there a better way of limiting the code size? rather than list the all individually? This will help increase the speed and reduce the program size.

Thank you.

```
private void btnCheckNumbs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= Globals.NextBalls; i++)
        {
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 1) txtBoxs1.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 2) txtBoxs2.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 3) txtBoxs3.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 4) txtBoxs4.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 5) txtBoxs5.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 6) txtBoxs6.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 7) txtBoxs7.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 8) txtBoxs8.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 9) txtBoxs9.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 10) txtBoxs10.BackColor = Color.Aqua;

            if (Globals.balls[i] == 11) txtBoxs11.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 12) txtBoxs12.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 13) txtBoxs13.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 14) txtBoxs14.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 15) txtBoxs15.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 16) txtBoxs16.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 17) txtBoxs17.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 18) txtBoxs18.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 19) txtBoxs19.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (Globals.balls[i] == 20) txtBoxs20.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
```

The statement goes up to 90....

Comment: Sounds like you should have *one* variable - `textBoxes` - which is an array or a collection. You really don't want to have 90 different variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Globals.NextBalls; i++)
{

    for (int k = 1; k <= 90; k++)
    {
        if (Globals.balls[i] == k) 
        {
            TextBox txtName =  (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtBoxs"+k.ToString(), true)[0];
            txtName.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The if statement doesn't seem right. If the index and ball value don't line up, it would never be true.

Comment: Error 'int' does not contain a definition for 'toString' and no extension method 'toString' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also thank you for fast feedback much appreciated

Comment: Found the error .toString needs to be .ToString C# is case sensitive

Comment: Working a charm, thank you very much everyone and especially Ashkufaraz.

Comment: your well come @WhitenaCording

Comment: Sorry to take more of your time, I created a text box to count how many numbers have been called in my bingo machine. Do you have any idea how this is done? @ashkufaraz Thank you.